# solving an equation by factoring

Tags: factoring

Need help solving an equation by factoring.

**PROBLEM:**  $3v^2-10v-12 = -28v + 36$

This is my solution, but it seems a little too much for school:

> $3v^2+18v-48 = 0$
>
> $3(v^2+18v-48) = 0$
>
> $3((-1v + -8)(-1v + 2)) = 0$
>
> $-1v + -8 = 0$
>
> **$v = -8$**
>
> $-1v + 2 = 0$
>
> **$v = 2$**

Comment: I don't know if it's too much for school, but it's wrong for math. Careful when you factor out that $3$!

Comment: Your second equation is incorrect. Then the factorization is mysteriously correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algebra went astray: from $3v^2-10v-12=-28v+36$ you should get

$$3v^2+18v-48=0\;.$$

**Then** you can factor out the $3$ to get $3(v^2+6v-16)=0$, so $v^2+6v-16=0$, and this then factors nicely to give you $(v+8)(v-2)=0$.

You actually made compensating errors, since $3(v^2+18v-48)$ does **not** factor as

$$3\big((−1v+−8)(−1v+2)\big)\;;$$

your $$3\big((−1v+−8)(−1v+2)\big)=0$$ is actually equivalent to

$$3(v+8)(v-2)=0\;,$$

which is essentially what I got.

Comment: OP got the right factors, so the misfactoring of the $3$ looks like a transcription error.

Comment: My answer is probably wrong because I've been using online calculators to check my work.  I guess I can't rely on them.

Comment: @Gerry: I realized that just after I posted the original version; I can’t tell whether it’s a transcription error or just sloppy notation $-$ I’ve seen plenty of both!

Comment: Thanks for your post Brian, It helped a lot.

Comment: @12japerk: You’re welcome.

Comment: I'm still confused by one small thing, when I get to 3(v+8)(v-2)=0 what should I do with the 3?  I tried doing 3v+8=0 (and solving for v, but got a wrong answer.  Any more help?

Comment: @12japerk: Just divide both sides of the equation by $3$ to get $(v+8)(v-2)=0$. That’s the practical, computational answer. A slightly deeper answer: use the fact that a product is $0$ if and only if at least one of the factors is $0$. $3\ne 0$, so $3(v+8)(v-2)=0$ if and only if at least one of $v+8$ and $v-2$ is $0$.

Comment: =\ That only confused me more.  Are you saying to divide 0 by 3 which would clear it from the left side?

Comment: @12japerk: Sure: you’re just multiplying both sides by the non-zero number $\frac13$, which is always allowable.